# Small entities that have associations to big, rarely changed entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I struggle with how to properly implement a logical model, where an entity `A` (lightweight, many instances) has a reference to entity `B` (heavyweight, few instances and only rarely modified).

Actually it would be nice, if all the instances of `B` were permanently cached and entity `A` were only holding the id of its `B`, so that entity `A` could on demand look up its `B` through some service.

But that whould mean, that `A` would has to have access to that service. That brings up the question where that service instance comes from? If `A` gets it through some static factory, then there is an ugly coupling. Adding a parameter to every method of `A`, that needs `B`, providing the service from outside seems better, but still not the best way to go.

Any suggestions?

Comment: When `A` holds the foreign key to `B`, it might suffice to cache `B` via second level cache so that each time someone loads an `A` and JPA would be triggered to load the appropriate `B` by the FK, the second level cache for `B` would match instead.

Comment: Exactly, this sounds like a perfect case for `ENABLE_SELECTIVE` second level caching.